# How to get outlinet version of assignment_returned Material Font icon using MatIcon?

Tags: angular, angular-material

It may be stupid question as I myself just got brain******, but why I cannot get outlined version of this icon?

https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=%20assignment&icon=assignment_returned&style=outline

```
<mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
<mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon> -- works fine
<mat-icon>assignment</mat-icon>
<mat-icon>assignment_outline</mat-icon>--does not work
```

[image]

Why this works for info but not for assignment? Is it new icon and will not work with angular material 5 or what?

You can try it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxc9um?file=app/icon-overview-example.html

Comment: Great downvote!

Comment: I am too interested in this. I checked random icons: only one in a few works with suffix "_outline".

Comment: @dzejdzej thats the point - icons webpages suggest that there are outline version my icons, but in example tab markup does not change. Makes me curious.